# How to make x and y axes appear with networkx nx.draw()?

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I have some code that creates a graph. However, I don't understand how to let the x and y axes appear. I have tried `ax.tick_params(left=True, bottom=True, labelleft=True, labelbottom=True)` but it doesn't work.

My code

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Adj = np.random.randint(0,2,(5,5))

x = np.random.uniform(0,1,5)
y = np.random.uniform(0,1,5)
# convert to list of tuples
M_pos = list(zip(x,y))
# give each neuron a number, and put in a dictionary
nums = list(range(0,5))
pos_dict = dict(zip(nums,M_pos))
# construct the graph from the neuron positions and adjacency matrix
GR = nx.from_numpy_matrix(Adj, pos_dict);

figure(figsize=(10, 5))
plt.title('Neuron spatial location')
#nx.draw_networkx_labels(GR, pos_dict)
nx.draw(GR, pos_dict, node_size=40, node_color='b');
```

Comment: You should define the ax parameter in nx.draw I think, I'll give it a shot when I have time a bit later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create an axis instance and pass to `nx.draw`:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))
plt.title('Neuron spatial location')
#nx.draw_networkx_labels(GR, pos_dict)
nx.draw(GR, pos_dict, node_size=40, node_color='b', ax=ax)

# turn the axis on
ax.set_axis_on()
ax.tick_params(left=True, bottom=True, labelleft=True, labelbottom=True)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This answer really helped me to display the axis, thanks.